# Acessing subclass variable from base class object

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, com

Let's say i'm having the following classes in c++

```
class Animal{}
```

```
class Dog : public Animal {
    int barkingVolume;
}
```

However, i don't have the header file for Dog class. But i have the object of Dog of type Animal at runtime.
The question is how I can access the variable **barkingVolume**?

`Animal animalButDogObject;//someone has set the value  at runtime`

I need to access barkingVolume from animalButDogObject.

*Actual scenario from COM/Directshow: I'm having IBaseFilter object which is of type IVendorFilter(custom filter from 3rd party vendor which extended IBaseFilter). While debugging using Visual studio i can see the type is IVendorFilter and it has variables which i need to change. However i cannot figure out how to do it. I cannot find anything like a reflection/evalutation in CPP*

Comment: Wrong language? `extends` is not C++. Assuming you meant `: public` then no you cannot access it.

Comment: It's just a psuedo code. I think there may be some way as the visual studio is able to access or read it during debug.

Comment: You're out of C++ language there. Now, on a specific platform, with a specific version of specific tools you can go beyond the guarantees and try to make something. It will be very complex (eg reading debugging information from the pdb, which are in undocumented format and change at every VS release), and it will probably break as soon as you upgrade anything.

Comment: Since it's a COM object, I would think that `QueryInterface()` would work.

Comment: You need the interface type to be accessible to your code for that.

Comment: "It's just a psuedo code." Seems like detail might matter here. Like knowing what language features are being used.

Comment: Seems like you don't understand COM, and are now trying to solve a midiagnosed problem in a way the system neither supports nor was designed to be used like. [Component Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) briefly introduces the technology. It's a good starting point, not an exhaustive reference.

Comment: I'll edit the code if the extends confuses you.

Comment: @IInspectable System may not be designed for it, but I need to do what I need to do. I don't know the whole of COM, but I know how to query an Interface and I'm able to get the interface that i wanted. Now I need to cast the type to Vendor type for accessing its values.I'm not able to do this part. If you know COM well, please advise how to do it. I have gone through the COM documentation before posting the question.

Comment: You MUST not ever cast an interface pointer to a specific interface implementation pointer. A **fundamental** COM rule. The immediate issue you need to solve is to stop confusing the implementation for the interface. Once that has happened you will drop the idea to muck with implementation details. The next step is to find a real solution.

Comment: A variable declared as `Animal animalButDogObject;` can only be of type `Animal`; it can't somehow hold an object of type `Dog` (if nothing else, there's not enough space; `sizeof(animalButDogObject) < sizeof(Dog)`, in all likelihood).

Comment: If you have an `Animal*` *pointer* to a `Dog` *object*, the only way to access the `barkingVolume` member is to type-cast the `Animal*` pointer to a `Dog*` pointer, but you need the full declaration of `Dog` in order to do that cast and access its members.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable is an object and not a pointer? For COM, you may need a pointer to get the interface: [QueryInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(q))

Comment: There is no (useful) runtime reflection in C++. Your debugger is able to display object internals because it has access to the PDB (program database). That information isn't part of the executable code. It's not part of C++' object model. It's not even part of COM. There is no (sane) way for you to observe or change that implementation detail. You're going to have to give up chasing whatever you believe to be your solution. Start by identifying that actual *problem* you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather comment than post an answer, but can't due to lack of reputation, so here we go.

This is pretty bad, but if you know the exact layout of the class you must access, you could just forward declare the whole thing and `reinterpret_cast` the object you need.

```
// FooBar.cpp or something
namespace FooBar
{
    class Foo {};

    class Bar : public Foo
    {
        public:
            Bar(int ival, float fval) : ival(ival), fval(fval) {}
            int ival = 0;
            float fval = 0.0f;
    };
}

// OtherFile.cpp
class ForwardDeclaredBar
{
    public:
        int ival;
        float fval;
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    FooBar::Foo* foo = new FooBar::Bar(3, 2.7f);
    auto bar = reinterpret_cast<ForwardDeclaredBar*>(foo);
    std::cout << "ival = " << bar->ival << ", fval = " << bar->fval << std::endl; // shows expected values
    return 0;
}
```

Again, this is pretty bad since any changes to the "real" class will mess up your result (`reinterpret_cast` will just shove whatever data it finds into the format you specified).

There are probably many other reasons which I've no idea about. I'm also unsure how well (if at all) this plays with more complex objects.

Comment: This is undefined behavior. The compiler is free to treat this however it wants, even if that means just not emitting code for this when optimized. This isn't just bad, this is dangerous.

Comment: Agreed. When I said "pretty bad", that's what I meant, but I should've been clearer. It's also why I didn't want to post an actual answer. Then  again, I didn't want to just not say anything, since it could be that OP was willing to rely on UB, as unadvised as that is.

Comment: It's **never** worth knowingly suggesting anything that is UB. UB has no guarantees that it will work for any implementation. Even if it *does* work on a given compiler, there is no guarantee that things like an optimization flags or even compiler upgrades might not break it; it's beyond brittle. If this were implementation-defined behavior, this would be a different story -- because users may be willing to fix themselves to a particular system... But UB never offers any guarantees; it's objectively bad.

Answer (score -1):

declare method on Animal (base) class and overwrite it on Dog (derived) class.

```
// Base class
class Animal
{
public:
    virtual int getBarkingVolume() = 0;
};

// Derived class
class Dog : public Animal 
{
private:
    int barkingVolume = 8;

public:
    int getBarkingVolume()
    {
        return barkingVolume;
    }
};
```

In main method has Animal (base) type and each derived class that implements the appropriate method (getBarkingVolume) will be compatible with that type.

```
int main()
{
    Animal* animal = new Dog();

    std::cout<<"barking: "<< animal->getBarkingVolume();
}
```

Comment: To quote directly verbatim from the question: "**Actual scenario from COM/Directshow: I'm having IBaseFilter object which is of type IVendorFilter(custom filter from 3rd party vendor which extended IBaseFilter)**". When code comes from a third-party vendor, very seldomly can you simply request that they give access by slapping a new function on the interface. It might even be that it simply doesn't **work** on the interface in terms of design (`getBarkingVolume` in this example is a blatant disregard for SOLID design practices)